# Bayes theorem: Can some one explain in plain words how argmax is used here?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

According to Bayes theorem

$$p(y |x) = \frac{p(x |y) p(y)}{p(x)}$$

So, to find the maximal value for $p(y |x)$, we want to compute:

\begin{align}
&\arg\max_{y\in Y} p(y|x) \\
=&\arg\max_{y\in Y} \frac{p(x |y) p(y)}{p(x)}\\
=&\arg\max_{y\in Y}p(x |y) p(y)
\end{align}

So, why we are ignoring $p(x)$ on the last line here?? Can some one explain in plain words?

Comment: I guess "to find the best value for $p(y|x)$" means that you are given $x$ and want to find the $y$ for which $p(y|x)$ is maximal, but I think this question would be easier to read if you stated the problem you are solving by taking $\mathrm{argmax}$ more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is **not** saying that
$$\frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{p(x)} \underbrace{=}_{\text{Not true!}} p(x|y)p(y). $$
However, the $y$ that maximizes the former term is the same $y$ that maximizes the numerator, since the denominator does not depend on $y$.

Comment: nice "English" language way to express it.

Comment: +1. The good thing about this in real situations is that often the denominator in these Bayesian calculations is a "normalization constant" which is actually very difficult to compute. Yet finding things like the maximum likelihood estimator doesn't require us to compute it, because of this result.

Answer (score 1):

Because the term $p(x)$ is same for $\forall y \in Y$.